# How to set control access to files inside ipa

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, ios-simulator

I have an ipa file which had some sensitive information embedded. When some one opens the ipa or views the contents using iExplorer they were able to view the information present in it. Is there a way that I can make the users preventing from accessing the files inside the ipa. If so please specify

Comment: You could always encrypt them, and then when your app launches, copy it to the device and decrypt it...  People will always find a way to get to your information though, if they want it bad enough.  (At least it will keep the casual user out.)

Comment: Thank you can you suggest any best suitable algorithms for this. I have different type of files to be encrypted. Can I hide them on the device itself was it possible

Comment: Take a look at Apple's [General Purpose Crypto](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/Conceptual/cryptoservices/GeneralPurposeCrypto/GeneralPurposeCrypto.html) document for options on decrypting data on iOS.

Comment: You'll have to find a way to decrypt the files without including the key in the bundle, storing the key on the device file system, or transmitting the key to the application in a way the user can intercept. Even then storing the key in memory will render you vulnerable. I think the direction to go is an SSL connection that only trusts your server's certificate and no other to prevent user from proxying with self signed cert, and transmitting key that way, every time your application needs the key.

Answer (score 0):

No. If your app is able to read and decrypt the files, anyone with a jailbroken phone can attach a debugger and dump the same data.